# Convert an object, containing JSON, to it's matching class definition

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

In a Controller, defined in my Web API, I have this action:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/validation/validate/")]
public IHttpActionResult Validate(FromBody]object instance)
{
    ...
}
```

*The parameter needs to be of type object, because it's a single point of entry that should support any type.*

Internally that will lead to this code:

```
var personDto = (PersonDto)this.ValidationInfo.Instance;
```

That doesn't work, because I get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type
>   'PersonDto'.

Instead, I tried to deserialize:

```
var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonModel>(this.ValidationInfo.Instance);
```

But that doesn't work either, because `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` expects a string.

What do I do to solve this?

**Addendum**

```
public class ValidationInfo
{
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public ValidationContext ValidationContext { get; set; }
    public object Instance { get; set; }
}

public sealed class ValidationContext
{
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    public DossierTypes DossierType { get; set; }
    public RoleTypes RoleType { get; set; }
}
```

***Usage***

```
self.ValidateServerAsync = function (entityInstance) {
    var uri = "api/validation/validate/";

    return apiService.Put(uri, entityInstance);
}
```

The above is a function in a custom written `ValidationService`, the used `apiService` handles the `$http` put. Both are AngularJS services.
*(Don't think I need to go into them because they work)*

Comment: Where does `ValidationInfo.Instance` come from?

Comment: @croxy: I've added it's code. It's a result of the validation process (a wrapper of extra info around the instance) which I don't think adds much to the core mechanism.

Comment: Could you add an example of how you call this controller?

Comment: cast the object to a string? Or use a ToString() overload?

Comment: @croxy: Updated (it's pseudo code as I can't go into too much detail).

Comment: maybe you can try to serialize again and deserialize into PersonDto or use object mapper to convert the object to PersonDto